# ASP.Net MVC ASPNETCOMPILER issues after adding .Net Standard 2.0 package

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I have created some helper libraries (NuGet) and these work fine in my various .Net FullFramework and .Net Core applications.

However, when I add them to a particularly complicated Asp.Net MVC (.Net 4.7.2) web application, I get the following errors:

1. The type 'System.Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to the assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....
2. The type 'System.IComparable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to the assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....
3. The type 'System.IFormattable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to the assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....
4. The type 'System.IConvertable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to the assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....
5. The type 'System.ValueType' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.  You must add a reference to the assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=....

In the "output" window, the last few are showing as:

> ASPNETCOMPILER : error CS0455: Type parameter 'T' inherits conflicting
>   constraints 'System.IFormattable' and 'System.IComparable'

My NuGet packages (A, B, C D and E) themselves have the following NuGet packages:

**PackageA** - `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>`

- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers 2.98
- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118

**PackageB** - `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>`

- PackageA
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers 2.98
- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- Newtonsoft.Json 12.0.3
- StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118
- System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager 4.7.0
- System.Data.SqlClient 4.8.1

**PackageC** - `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>`

- PackageB
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers 2.98
- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118
- System.Diagnostics.EventLog 4.7.0

**PackageD** - `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>`

- PackageC
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers 2.98
- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118
- System.Runtime.Caching 4.7.0

**PackageE** - `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1</TargetFrameworks>`

- PackageD
- Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers 2.98
- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118

I've tried the following, either all together, or one at a time...no luck.

1. Added a NuGet reference to NETStandard.Library (2.0.3) and also tried 2.0.0 (because that was what was specifically asked for).
2. Added `<Reference Include="netstandard" />` to my *.csprog file

Answer (score 0):

Finally, solved this by changing my web.config from

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
```

to

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" > 
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/> 
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Thanks to this post by [David Sekar](https://davidsekar.com/asp-net/you-must-add-a-reference-to-assembly-netstandard).